# How to validate request parameters in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

Here s my CODE to start with:

**PersonController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/person", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> addPerson(@Valid Person p, HttpServletResponse response) {
        ...
    }
```

**Person.java**

```
public class Person {    

    @NotNull
    String name;    

    @NotNull
    int age;    

    String gender;
}
```

**The requirement is**: When a POST request is made to /person, I want an exception to be thrown if the user did not specify a key for the string **Name** in the BODY of the request. The annotation `@NotNull` does not do this.

Is there another annotation that I can use in Person.java to achieve this? If not, is there some validation I could do in the **addPerson** method to ensure that an exception is thrown if one of the mandatory parameters are not there?

Comment: There are couple of annotations using `Hibernate`, `@NotBlank`, `@NotEmpty`

Comment: @RossiRobinsion is there one that validates an int? Essentially what I'm looking for is an `@Required` constraint.

Comment: There are couple of them like.. `@Min`, `@Digits`

Comment: @RossiRobinsion these only validate the parameters IF they are passed. I want an annotation that makes sure that a parameter is indeed passed and throws an error if it's not specified.

Comment: Can't you use multiple annotations? `@NotNull`, `@Digits`

Comment: No, because those annotations only validate the **value**. They don't check to see if the **key** exists.

Comment: Can you elaborate key exists meaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the `@NotNull` annotation does exactly what you want but unfortunately it can't do it on `int` type since it can't be `null`. In order for it to work you need to change the age to `Integer` and then after the spring does the binding of values if both parameters are passed and they have values the validation will pass. Otherwise if they are passed with empty value or not passed at all the value will be `null` and the validation will fail. Just make sure that you don't have some constructor for `Person` that initializes the attributes to some values.

If you don't want to change it and use an `int` you can add `HttpServletRequest request` to the method arguments and check if there is a parameter `age` present with:

```
request.getParameter('age');
```

If it is `null` then no parameter was passed at all.

*Hint: It may be that you are missing some configuration and the annotation are not processed at all, something like `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` or `@EnableWebMvc` or maybe you are missing an actual validator implementation like [Hibernate Validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/). It is hard to tell without a sample of your configuration.*

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: I am glad that I helped you. Please be kind and accept it as an answer :)

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to encapsulate the fields in your domain-classes. The spring container will use these getters and setters to manipulate the object.

Then, you can add [constraints to these getters and setters (Bean Validation)](http://beanvalidation.org/2.0/spec/). If you added them correctly, Spring will catch errors when using the @Valid annotation (which you did). These errors will be added to the BindingResult, and can be shown in a jsp by using the Spring form tags.

```
<form:errors path="field_that_was_manipulated_incorrectly" />
```